No found replica set
I deployed a 3meta+2querytekv cnosdb cluster in a windows environment.
After successful deployment, run the sqllogic use case and find an error when executing a written use case:No found replica set.
the detail as follow:

has any encount the error? Why cannot find the repllica?

It appears that the metadata of the meta node was not observed when writing the nodes.
